# Problema com construtor

Tags: c#

Este é o código da minha classe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace Banco_Exercicio1
{
    public class Conta
    {
        public string Titular { get; set; }
        public double Saldo { get; set; }
        public int Numero { get; set; }

        public Conta(String nome)
        {
            Titular = nome;
        }

        public double Depositar(double Valor)
        {
            Saldo += Valor;
            return Saldo; 
        }

        public virtual void Saca(double Valor)
        {
            Saldo -= Valor;
        }
    }

    public class ContaPoupanca : Conta
    {
        public override void Saca(double Valor)
        {
            base.Saca(Valor + 0.10);    
        }      
    }
}
```

Este é o código do meu form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Banco_Exercicio1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Conta conta;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conta = new Conta ("Victor")
            {
               Numero = 1 , 
               Saldo = 0   
            };

            TBtextoTitular.Text = conta.Titular;
            TBtextoNumero.Text = Convert.ToString(conta.Numero);
            TBtextoSaldo.Text = Convert.ToString(conta.Saldo); 
        }

        private void deposito_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conta.Depositar(Convert.ToDouble(TBtextoValor.Text));
            TBtextoSaldo.Text = Convert.ToString(conta.Saldo); 
        }
    }
}
```

Estou com o seguinte erro:

> Banco_Exercicio1.Conta does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

Como consigo resolver?

Comment: Mesmo compartilhado no link passado, poste o conteúdo pois o link pode se tornar desativado.

Comment: Que erro você está tendo?

Comment: @brasofilo - Falha minha. Corrigido.

Comment: uma vez que `ContaPoupanca` herda da `Conta`, ela precisa ter um construtor que receba no minimo a string do nome.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 3):

Este erro está acontecendo pois `ContaPoupanca` que herda da classe `Conta` está implementada sem construtor, o que faz com que o C# gere um construtor padrão que chama o construtor da base que possui 0 argumentos... só que este construtor da classe de base não existe. Só existe um que tem 1 argumento `nome`.

Dessa forma, é necessário que tome uma dessas medidas:

- adicionar construtor com 0 argumento na classe `Conta`

  ```
  public class Conta
  {
      public Conta() { ...
  ```
- adicionar um construtor na classe `ContaPoupanca` manualmente, e chamar o construtor da classe de base, passando um parâmetro válido

  ```
  public class ContaPoupanca
  {
      public ContaPoupanca(string nome)
          : base(nome)
      { ...
  ```